# Is there any payment way increase google-assistant-sdk quota limit for specific project/user on request?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I use Google Assistant API to control my google home device, but Developers just can prototype with the API up to 500 queries/project/day.
Is there any payment way to increase the google-assistant-sdk quota?

Comment: Did you find some payment methods for that?

Comment: Did you manage to find any details about this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do if you encounter this issue is, go here:

1. https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas
2. Please ensure you selected the project at the top that is meeting
   its quota.
3. Then, put a checkmark by the quota that's over its limit (Google Assistant API)
4. Then click "Edit Quotas" at the top.
5. On the right pop-out, click "apply for higher quota".
6. From there, you must fill out the form and hope they get back to
   you.  I'll update this answer if they do.

I have no problem giving them money for the service, but they make it entirely too hard!